# why I get repeated object from List<E> in C#?

Tags: c#, list, oop

**this is my question function, I send the collection of data to the ShuffledList function in order to get one row at a time**

```
  private void nextQuestion_Question()
    {
            ql1 = ShuffleList(ql1);
            currentQuestion_List = ql1.ElementAt(0);
            //ql1.RemoveAt(0);

            txtQ.Text = currentQuestion_List.text;
            btnA.Text = currentQuestion_List.a;
            btnB.Text = currentQuestion_List.b;
            btnC.Text = currentQuestion_List.c;
            btnD.Text = currentQuestion_List.d;

    }
```

**but this function some times it returns repeated objects**

```
private List<E> ShuffleList<E>(List<E> inputList)
    {
        List<E> randomList = new List<E>();
        Random r = new Random();
        int randomIndex = 0;  
               while (inputList.Count>0)
                {
                   randomIndex = r.Next(inputList.Count); //Choose a random object in the list
                    randomList.Add(inputList[randomIndex]); //add it to the new, random list
                    inputList.RemoveAt(randomIndex); //remove to avoid duplicates          
                }
        return randomList; //return the new random list
    }
```

> note I'm try to make a multi choices game and it works well but some times repeat the same questions
>   please if you can help me to solve this issue

Comment: Your ShuffleList is flawed.  It is more efficient as an in-place suffle swapping elements;you should use the same random object for the life of the app; a proper shuffle loops backwards so that each element is swapped once and once only.  Then shuffle only once per game

Comment: I'm also try to do as you said but it's not working with me could correct it ?

Comment: There are many many answers here showing how to dshuffle properly

Answer (score 2):

I think you problem in your repeatable shuffles. Try to store shuffled list once to prevent case when you generate the same question position twice during game session

```
bool listShuffled = false;
private void nextQuestion_Question()
{
        if(!listShuffled){
            listShuffled = true;
            ql1 = ShuffleList(ql1);
        }

        currentQuestion_List = ql1.ElementAt(0);
        //ql1.RemoveAt(0);

        txtQ.Text = currentQuestion_List.text;
        btnA.Text = currentQuestion_List.a;
        btnB.Text = currentQuestion_List.b;
        btnC.Text = currentQuestion_List.c;
        btnD.Text = currentQuestion_List.d;

}
```

Comment: Dear @Nigrimmist it returns the same object all the times

Comment: Do you need every next question unique? If yes - you need to use queue. if random - just to user new Random().Next(0,ql1.count-1) instead of 0 el pos.

Comment: I want each question appear once but randomly

Comment: Ok, that's mean that you need shuffle, and then - get then one by one. Queue https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7977ey2c(v=vs.110).aspx is what do you need.